# Problems when querying mysql tables in phpmyadmin from Google Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, nginx, phpmyadmin

I will tell you briefly what is happening, since last week I am having problems in viewing tables from my browser. The issue is to solve if it is on the part of my service that deploys phpmyadmin or is this error in general since I have tried with other mysqlphp the same thing happens to me since a week ago.

[image: Message that pops up every time I query a table]

This happens every time I query a table in phpmyadmin and this is the complete error:

```
{
"pma_version": "5.2.1",
"browser_name": "CHROME",
"browser_version": "114.0.0.0",
"user_os": "Win",
"server_software": "nginx/1.18.0",
"user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
"locale": "en",
"configuration_storage": "disabled",
"php_version": "8.1.20",
"script_name": "index.php",
"exception_type": "js",
"exception": {
    "mode": "stack",
    "name": "TypeError",
    "message": "CodeMirror.runMode is not a function",
    "stack": [
        {
            "func": "HTMLElement.<anonymous>",
            "line": "1623",
            "column": "20",
            "context": [
                "    /* We only care about visible elements to avoid double processing */",
                "    if ($pre.is(':visible')) {",
                "      var $highlight = $('<div class=\"sql-highlight cm-s-default\"></div>');",
                "      $sql.append($highlight);",
                "      if (typeof CodeMirror !== 'undefined') {",
                "        CodeMirror.runMode($sql.text(), 'text/x-mysql', $highlight[0]);",
                "        $pre.hide();",
                "        $highlight.find('.cm-keyword').each(Functions.documentationKeyword);",
                "        $highlight.find('.cm-builtin').each(Functions.documentationBuiltin);",
                "      }",
                "    }"
            ],
            "uri": "js/dist/functions.js?v=5.2.1",
            "scriptname": "js/dist/functions.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "Function.each",
            "line": "2",
            "column": "3003",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v3.6.3 | (c) OpenJS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.o//...",
                "!function(e,t){\"use strict\";\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof modul//...",
                ""
            ],
            "uri": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=5.2.1",
            "scriptname": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "e.<computed>.each",
            "line": "2",
            "column": "1481",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v3.6.3 | (c) OpenJS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.o//...",
                "!function(e,t){\"use strict\";\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof modul//...",
                ""
            ],
            "uri": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=5.2.1",
            "scriptname": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "Functions.highlightSql",
            "line": "1615",
            "column": "8",
            "context": [
                " *",
                " * @param $base",
                " */",
                "Functions.highlightSql = function ($base) {",
                "  var $elm = $base.find('code.sql');",
                "  $elm.each(function () {",
                "    var $sql = $(this);",
                "    var $pre = $sql.find('pre');",
                "    /* We only care about visible elements to avoid double processing */",
                "    if ($pre.is(':visible')) {",
                "      var $highlight = $('<div class=\"sql-highlight cm-s-default\"></div>');"
            ],
            "uri": "js/dist/functions.js?v=5.2.1",
            "scriptname": "js/dist/functions.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "?",
            "line": "495",
            "column": "21",
            "context": [
                "        // been added outside of #page_content",
                "        $('body').children().not('div.modal').not('#pma_navigation').not('#//...",
                "        // Replace #page_content with new content",
                "        if (data.message && data.message.length > 0) {",
                "          $('#page_content').replaceWith('<div id=\\'page_content\\'>' + data//...",
                "          Functions.highlightSql($('#page_content'));",
                "          Functions.checkNumberOfFields();",
                "        }",
                "        if (data.selflink) {",
                "          var source = data.selflink.split('?')[0];",
                "          // Check for faulty links"
            ],
            "uri": "js/dist/ajax.js?v=5.2.1",
            "scriptname": "js/dist/ajax.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "Object.reset",
            "line": "745",
            "column": "7",
            "context": [
                "       * Re-attach a generic event handler to clicks",
                "       * on pages and submissions of forms",
                "       */",
                "      $(document).off('click', 'a').on('click', 'a', AJAX.requestHandler);",
                "      $(document).off('submit', 'form').on('submit', 'form', AJAX.requestHa//...",
                "      callback();",
                "    }",
                "  }",
                "};",
                "",
                "/**"
            ],
            "uri": "js/dist/ajax.js?v=5.2.1",
            "scriptname": "js/dist/ajax.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "Object.responseHandler [as success]",
            "line": "468",
            "column": "26",
            "context": [
                "        Functions.ajaxShowMessage(data.redirect, false);",
                "        AJAX.active = false;",
                "        AJAX.xhr = null;",
                "        return;",
                "      }",
                "      AJAX.scriptHandler.reset(function () {",
                "        if (data.reloadNavigation) {",
                "          Navigation.reload();",
                "        }",
                "        if (data.title) {",
                "          $('title').replaceWith(data.title);"
            ],
            "uri": "js/dist/ajax.js?v=5.2.1",
            "scriptname": "js/dist/ajax.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "c",
            "line": "2",
            "column": "28599",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v3.6.3 | (c) OpenJS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.o//...",
                "!function(e,t){\"use strict\";\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof modul//...",
                ""
            ],
            "uri": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=5.2.1",
            "scriptname": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "Object.fireWith [as resolveWith]",
            "line": "2",
            "column": "29344",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v3.6.3 | (c) OpenJS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.o//...",
                "!function(e,t){\"use strict\";\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof modul//...",
                ""
            ],
            "uri": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=5.2.1",
            "scriptname": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "l",
            "line": "2",
            "column": "80328",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v3.6.3 | (c) OpenJS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.o//...",
                "!function(e,t){\"use strict\";\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof modul//...",
                ""
            ],
            "uri": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=5.2.1",
            "scriptname": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"
        }
    ],
    "uri": "index.php?route=%2Fsql&pos=0"
} }
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me with this problem.

Comment: I found the problem, for those who have a similar error that only have error in your browser and specifically google chrome.... check well the installed extensions, I had one that only affected phpmyadmin but only with uninstalling served. My recommendation is densintalar everything you have in the browser and go installing little by little until you reach the conflicting extension.